# Where to put AysncTask class in a ListActivity

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

I have class which extends ListActivity and sets the adapter, and a adapter class which populates the view with data from a DB. I wanted to add a progress dialog programmicatlly in the List activity class as the views are been populated and wrap the time consuming tasks in asynch inner class.

I am wondering where is the best place to implement the asynch task, i plan too incorporate the dialog progress in pre Execute and post Execute.

Code form list activity class onCreate :

```
data = new diveDataBase(this);
data.open();
cursor = data.getCursorData();

//check if data available
if(cursor!=null && cursor.getCount()>0){
    // get customised array adoater list
    adapter = new ItemAdapter(this, cursor);

    this.setListAdapter(adapter);
    data.close();
}
```

And the adapter class bind view method with the cursor object passed as a parameter:

```
String diveSite = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(diveDataBase.KEY_DIVESITE));
String date = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(diveDataBase.KEY__DIVEDATE));
String diveNumber= c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(diveDataBase.KEY__DIVENUMBER));
String diveImagePath = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(diveDataBase.KEY_DIVEPICTURE));
String rating = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(diveDataBase.KEY_DIVERATING));

/**
 * Next set the dive site name
 */

TextView title_text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_DiveSiteListView);
if (title_text != null) {
       title_text.setText(diveSite);
}
//populate another textview and image view etc
```

Edit: My Code for aycnh class

So I ended u wrapping the code for getting the DB cursor in the do-in-background and creation of adapter and setting it in the the post-execute, is this the best way as the DB at the moment is not large enough to test:

```
        @Override 
        protected Cursor doInBackground(Void... params) { 


>                       ViewListOfDives.data = new diveDataBase(ViewListOfDives.this);
>                       ViewListOfDives.data.open();
>                       // get cursor object holding all data, use a asynch inner class to load 
>                       cursor = data.getCursorData();
> 
>                       
>                                   return cursor;      
}

> @Override         
protected void onPostExecute(Cursor cursor) { 
                    if(pd.isShowing()){
>                       pd.dismiss();           }
>                       //check if data available
>                       if(cursor!=null && cursor.getCount()>0){
>                       // get customised array adoater list
>                       adapter = new ItemAdapter(ViewListOfDives.this, cursor);
>                       }else{
>                           
>                               //display o dives in data base message and finish this activity
>                               displayDialog();
>                           
>                       }
>                       ViewListOfDives.this.setListAdapter(adapter);
>                       ViewListOfDives.data.close();           super.onPostExecute(cursor);        }
> 
> 
> 
>
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually do it in onResume() and then have the result pass a message to the Handler which updates the List's Adapter.  If you don'e ever need to refresh the data more than once, if someone comes back to the Activity in the stack, you could do it in onCreate().